# How to make a condition on it? PHP

Tags: php, html, php-5.5

I'm having difficulty in adding student information. I would like that my program can save student info only once a year.

I have a problem in my code, because if I add idno=c24 then save it, it will then save but when I try again to add same idno it will again save. Please help on my condition that idno can save 1 idno(once a year) and has an error message that That idno is already registered on this year.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student VALUES ('$stud_id','$idno','$dept_id','$progid','$syear','0','$lastname','$firstname','‌​$middlename','$year')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if ($idno > 1) {
    echo"that idno has already exist with exact current year";
} else {
    mysql_query("insert into users (stud_id,password,user_type) values('$stud_id','$password','$user_type')")or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "alert('Successfully Added.');\n";
    echo "window.location = 'addusers.php';";
    echo "</script>";
} 
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't recommend using `mysql_` consider `mysqli_` or even `pdo` http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php it explains here that it has been `deprecated` as of  php 5.5

Comment: If you're going to the be using the depreciated `mysql_*` functions, I hope you're at least calling `mysql_real_escape_string` before injecting those variables into your query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check if the ID exists, if yes then alert the message and don't insert.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from student where idno = '$idno'") or die(mysql_error()); //check based on idno
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){ //idno exists
    echo"that idno has already exist with exact current year";
}else { //idno does not exist
     mysql_query("insert into users (stud_id,password,user_type) values('$stud_id','$password','$user_type')")or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "alert('Successfully Added.');\n";
    echo "window.location = 'addusers.php';";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

Final tip: do not continue to use mysql_ as it is deprecated on the newer version of PHP. Start learning to use mysqli_ instead.

Comment: You also really shouldn't use `*` for SELECT when doing a simple check.

Answer (score 0):

what about primary key?

```
ALTER TABLE student 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (idno)
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/

Comment: how, it didn't work $sql = mysql_query("select * from student where idno = '$idno'") or die(mysql_error()); //check based on idno
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){ //idno exists
    echo"that idno has already exist with exact current year";
}else { //idno does not exist
     mysql_query("insert into users (stud_id,password,user_type) values('$stud_id','$password','$user_type')")or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "alert('Successfully Added.');\n";
    echo "window.location = 'addusers.php';";
    echo "</script>";
}

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a column that can tell you the registered year of a student ？If so , you can create an unique index with the idno like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_idx01 on tableNAME(reg_year, idno);
```

then when you insert another row with the same year and idno , mysql will give an error (1062)

Comment: I have a schoolyear table which is syearid,year_from and to_from and the student table has syearid

Comment: @CamilleValerio CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_idx01 on student(syearid, idno);

Comment: $syear= $_POST['syearid'];
$YearNow=Date('Y');

$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student,school_year where idno = '$idno' AND  student.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow") or die(mysql_error()); //check based on idno student.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow
if(mysql_num_rows($sql1) > 0){ //idno exists
    echo"That $idno has already exist with an exact current year $YearNow";